# Why is why my VPN speed is very slow in a VirtualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox, vpn

I'm trying to figure out why my VPN speed is very slow in a VM. My VPN provider is NordVPN. I'm seeing the expected speed on other devices, e.g. laptop, Android phone and tablet, etc., so I've ruled out NordVPN as the culprit… Or at least I assume I have.

My host is Windows 7 (x64) and my guest is Windows 7 (x32) in VirtualBox. Here are the results of Ookla Speedtests using single connection:

- **Host**: Ping ms 21; Download Mbps 30.18; Upload Mbps 6.75
- **Guest without VPN**: Ping ms 24; Download Mbps 20.18; Upload Mbps 4.02
- **Guest with VPN**: Ping ms 31; Download Mbps 1.75; Upload Mbps 1.00

The minor drop in speed from host to guest without a VPN is expected I believe, but I'm floored at the drop from without VPN to with VPN.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: The host never has a VPN connection. The VPN is only ever enabled in the guest.

Comment: When you are performing these tasks is the Host connected to the VPN?  Edit your question, to include this vital information, instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Did you check if guest is not performing any background connection, like auto-update?

Comment: @Biswapriyo All disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound Done.

Comment: What is the CPU utilization during your tests?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is correct, but my best guess is that my VM is underpowered and simply handling the encryption aspect of the VPN connection is the bottleneck.